# Retrieve a flat Queryset of prefetch_related objects from a parent queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

If I have models like so:

```
class A(models.Model):
  ...


class B(models.Model):
  a = models.ForeignKey(A)


class C(models.Model): 
  b = models..ForeignKey(B)
```

I can get the full queryset:

```
qs = A.objects.all().prefetch_related('b_set', 'b_set__c_set')
>> <QuerySet [<A: A object (1)>, <A: A object (2)>, ... ]>
```

What I want to know is there a way to get all the `C` objects in a flattened queryset, e.g:

```
qs['b_set__c_set']
>> <QuerySet [<C: C object (1)>, <C: C object (2)>, ... ]>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a query on the C Model, just checking for all C's that have an `a` value? So

```
C.objects.filter(b__is_null=False, b__a__isnull=False)
```

Would that achieve what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid additional hits to the database by processing directly on the queryset.